# How can we compare processing times of two designs implemented on different FPGAs?

Tags: fpga, signal-processing, speed, clock-speed, timing-analysis

How can we compare two different designs that perform same task (e.g. processing a 256x256 image) and both implemented on different FPGAs, in terms of processing time(seconds)?

For example one of them is on Virtex-5 and other one is on Virtex-7. I know that these two families have different specifications in terms of speed grade, available resources, architecture etc. So I thought it is not convenient to do this comparison (a fair way to do it would be comparing clock cycle count). But I wanted to ask it because I came upon some papers which does this sort of thing. (e.g. compares a design implemented on Virtex-5 with a design implemented on Virtex-7 and claims that his/her design/implementation is faster in terms of seconds)

Edit:  I am normally doing this comparison by mapping my design onto the same family of FPGA used by the competitor.

Edit2:

A lot of time passed since I asked this question but I still feel that I have failed to describe the situation correctly.

You can achieve better timing results if you use technologically better FPGAs. Critical term is TIMING here. Do not assume that I will set the same timing constraint for both FPGAs. This is not the case. Please consider the question like that:

For Virtex-5: timing constraint is set to 100 MHz and it is met (T. constraint 105 Mhz Fails).

For Virtex-7: timing constraint is set to 150 MHz and it is met (155 Mhz fails). So I'm trying to find out the best achievable frequency for the device. Virtex-5 and Virtex-7 are just for the example. They may not have such a performance gap.

My architecture achieves better result if I use Virtex-7.

So now imagine that someone implements a circuit that performs the same task as my design.

He/She implements the circuit for Virtex-7 and achieves a max frequency of 130 MHz.

He then compares this result **(WITHOUT implementing it for Virtex-5)** with my Virtex-5 result (100 MHz) and concludes that his/her architecture is better. **Assume that clock cycles are equal for both circuits.**

In my opinion, if such a comparison to be made; it should be done by using same family of FPGA device. Otherwise it is not a fair comparison. Purpose of this question is to find out if there are exceptions to that.

Comment: It's kind of meaningless. You should know theoretically from your architecture how many clock cycles specific calculation is taking. And then just multiply it by the clock duration.

Comment: @EugeneSh. A more correct question would be "How" more than "Can"... Because sure you can compare the time of execution

Comment: You are right, thank you. @EugeneSh. That is what I normally thought but I wanted to learn if there is some valid reasons or some exceptions to do this kind of comparison.

Comment: @Chief Valid reasons could be some very complex algorithm, difficult to analyze in these terms, or some non-deterministic input data. If both are not the case, a theoretical calculation should be sufficient.

Comment: E.g. a pipelined architecture where implementation differences may affect the length of a specific instruction and affect assembler timing

Comment: I can see you are coming from SW background. FPGAs are not like processors, they do not perform things dynamically or change speed at run-time. When you synthesize your design, you will now the speek of your clock, that should give you an indication on how fast things are "executed" inside the FPGA. If you have 2 FPGAs that both use the 50MHz clock, the 'execution' time will be the same, but the implementation can be VERY different inside the FPGAs.

Comment: @FarhadA You are correct if both implementations done on the same FPGA (same family, same vendor etc.). We can than compare latency and operating frequency of two designs and determine better of the two. So for example if both of them are implemented on Virtex-5 FPGA and max operating freq. for both of them is 50 MHz and if the execution times are 5.04 ns and 9.34 ns respectively, we can say that 5.04ns is faster and that implementation is better in terms of speed. But as I indicated in the question, comparing Virtex-7 with Virtex-5 using only the execution time seems unfair.

Comment: Also by comparing two implementations, I don't include other parameters such as resource usage, power consumption, computational errors etc. I am just interested in execution time. So assume that all other parameters are equal except for the FPGA vendor/family and architecture (of the implemented design). I think Eugene Sh. and crasic pointed out some situations in which we can make that kind of comparison.

Comment: I don't understand your logic here. IF your deign is synchronous and you meet the timing, the design MUST behave EXACTLY the same way, no matter what the latency of the FPGA and the internal logic of the FPGA is, otherwise something is wrong with the design. I have compared same designs between various Altera and Xilinx products to verify their functionality and find oyur answer really confusing and hard to understand.